# How to merge multiple .IDML files without InDesign?

Tags: c#, xml, file, adobe, adobe-indesign

I wish to merge multiple .idml files without touching InDesign, I'm ideally trying to code this in C# but even python would do. I just need to know how to realize this in code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. It would be useful to know what you have tried so far and how it fails to achieve the desired result. The relevant part of your code would also be useful. As it stands, your questions is way too broad for this site.

Comment: Start by examining the contents of an IDML file. Then compare a single-page IDML to a multi-page IDML. Note the differences and write code to modify and augment the single-page IDML.